# How to compress multiple videos using FFMPEG while concatenating them

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using FFMPEG for concatenating multiple videos and it is working fine for some videos but for some videos it is not, and I think it is because of higher bit rates or higher size. We can compress video using FFMPEG but for that we need to execute separate command for one video this is very long process if we have more videos, so **is there any way to compress as well as concatenate multiple videos?**

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

I am using above command for concatenating video, input.txt containf list of videos to be merged. **I want to use same command to compress and concatenating videos.**

Comment: why you asking C# code,are u want command or code?

Comment: I am using FFMPEG through C#.Net application.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace copy with encoding parameters e.g.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 22050 output.mp4
```

Comment: I have already tried but it did not work, again it keep processing and wont come.

Comment: Show console output.

Comment: Try with express specification of parameters, like in edited command.

Comment: Thanks, If I use that command I am getting error, http://screencast.com/t/842aqyjmPV, if execute that command directly with FF Prompt and if I use that command with VS it keep processing and never returns. This issue is with some videos only not for all videos.

Answer (score -1):

**You can concatenate all the videos first and then compress the output video.**

**For Concatenating all Videos**:

```
#for writing first video file path in .txt file
echo file {videoPath} >  mylist.txt

#for writing otherthan first video file path in .txt file
echo file {videoPath} >>  mylist.txt

#for concatenating all videos appended in .txt file
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy {output_file}

#for clearing file
> mylist.txt
```

For concatenating videos it takes hardly 1-2 seconds.

**For Compressing Output Video**:

```
ffmpeg -i {output_file} -c:v libx264 -crf 40 -preset ultrafast {compressed_video_file}
```